# Openpyxl read 100% as 'int'

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to read an excel file using Openpyxl:

cell A1: 100%

cell A2： 89.3%

both of them are in percentage format in excel.

but when I read them in Openpyxl, it gets:

```
>>> type(ws['A1'].value)
<class 'int'>
>>> type(ws['A2'].value)
<class 'float'>
```

Is there a way to read the cell format of cell A1 as 'percentage', or just read it as float '1.00'?

I don't want to add a judgment in my code like 'value==1' or anything.

Comment: no percentage is class in python. You can cast to a float and then add a % later in formatting if you need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my solution when I posted my question half an hour ago ...

just check

```
cell.number_format
```

Example:

```
value = ws.cell(i, j).value
nf = ws.cell(i, j).number_format
if value == 1 and (nf =='0.0%' or nf == '0.00%'):
    value = '100%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could return something like

```
res = f"{value * 100}%"
```

so the 1.00 would be "100%"

Comment: thank you for your answer. I don't want to do a conversion like that since there may have other values that are just int '1' that should not be converted to.

Answer (score -1):

My first guess would be to use a method to remove all the % signs in the cella and store that to a new variable and convert that to an integer and then divide by 100 to get a floating point/integer number. It's a bit of a weird way to do it though.

Comment: thank you for your answer. My key is that I can't read the '%' character or the whole thing will become much easier.